# get_option in header.php not returning value from customizer

Tags: theme-development, themes, theme-options, theme-customizer

I've set up a new section in the customizer called *Social Links*, under which I've set up an option and text field control called *Facebook*. Here's the code in my *functions.php*:

```
// SOCIAL LINKS
$wp_customize->add_section( 'social_links_section' , array(
    'title'      => __( 'Social Links', 'my_theme' ),
    'priority'   => 100,
) );
// Facebook
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'social_link_facebook' , array(
    'default' => ''
) );
$wp_customize->add_control(
    'social_link_facebook', 
    array(
        'label'    => __( 'Facebook', 'my_theme' ),
        'section'  => 'social_links_section',
        'settings' => 'social_link_facebook',
        'type'     => 'url',
    )
);
```

But when I try to get the value of *social_link_facebook* in my theme template files, it isn't returning anything. Here's the code from my *header.php*:

```
<?php $facebook = get_option( 'social_link_facebook' );
if( !empty($facebook) ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $facebook ?>" target="_blank" ><span class="dashicons dashicons-facebook-alt"></span></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Any idea why this might be?

Comment: You should use [`get_theme_mod`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_mod).

Comment: @LuisSanz Thanks! I wasn't expecting it to be that simple, now I feel stupid :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this:

1 Keep the mods as they are and use `get_theme_mod` in stead of `get_option`

2 Store the mods as options by changing the setting:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'social_link_facebook' , array(
    'default' => '',
    'type' => 'option'
) );
```

Comment: Thanks, I used _get_theme_mod_ and that did the trick :)